# couchbase query node becomes unresponsive while running query via curl

Tags: curl, couchbase, sql++

I am running a query on my couchbase query node via curl, noticed the RAM usage on the query node spikes up to 97% very quickly and then the node becomes un-responsive and the curl request terminates with the error : `curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining`

below is my curl request:

```
curl http://<ip>:8093/query/service -u Administrator:<password> --data-urlencode 'statement=SELECT customerId,(ARRAY v.value FOR v IN p.events WHEN v.type = "Credit" AND v.funder like "TM%" END) AS credits FROM default AS p WHERE p.type = "account" AND p.schemeId = "some-scheme" AND (ANY e IN p.events SATISFIES e.funder LIKE "TM%" AND e.type = "Credit" END)' > /tmp/results.json
```

it's evident the RAM is being used completely and the machine freezes momentarily. Is there a way to limit the buffering by the query service? or is it something else?

Comment: Check EXPLAIN and try with cbq shell and see how much data you are fetching.

Comment: tried running with cbq within the query node, the same thing happens. While running from a data node, it ended with this error : `ERROR 175 : Error with io Writer. unexpected EOF`

Answer (score 0):

Are you receiving any portion of the data? My best guess is that your query is handling a lot of data and has some blocking operation, like sort or aggregation, that needs to consume all its inputs before producing any output. Use EXPLAIN  to check for that in the query.

Comment: Yes, when the curl command is issued it starts streaming the data for about 3 - 6 minutes until the node goes out of memory, So I do have data received until that point.

Comment: The query engine is probably leaking memory somewhere. Cases like this are normally handled by the support engineers and eventually bubble up to the dev team. If you don't have a support contract, try a couple of workarounds. First try to determine whether you need all the data you are retrieving. You may be fetching whole documents when you only need a couple of fields. Second, if that doesn't work, change your query to get just the document ids of the documents you need, and fetch the actual documents separately using the KV interfaces from the SDK.

Comment: We tried extracting the same data using a view and it pulled the same like a charm. Any harms using views ? 
The issue has been taken up with couchbase support and is still under investigation, shall update if we get to resolve this.  Thanks for the suggestions on the data extractions, we were thinking on the same lines as your latter approach.